# The position of "such as Google, Facebook, and Instagram"

Tags: grammar, word-order, prepositional-phrases, adverbial-phrases, adverb-placement

I'd like to learn what places fit "*such as Google, Facebook, and Instagram*" in the following sentence.

- The internet brought new applications into our lives *such as Google,
  Facebook, and Instagram.*
- The internet brought new applications *such as Google, Facebook, and Instagram* into our lives.
- *Such as Google, Facebook, and Instagram,* the internet brought new applications into our lives.

I think that the second one fits the intended meaning the best, the first and third ones are also grammatically correct although they are a bit clumsy.

Do you agree with me about it?

Thank you.

Comment: The third one makes no sense, because it says that "the internet" is "such as Google, Facebook, and Instagram".

Comment: Well, which one would you choose, if I asked you to do? The first one or second one is the best, most natural?

Comment: IMO the second one flows better than the first (third is no good). The first could be written as "The internet has brought new applications into our lives. Google, Facebook, and Instagram *[have had extraordinary success...]*"